# Python Drop duplicates to ignore case sensitive

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop-duplicates

I want to delete duplicates from the below df, preserving the case sensitivity.

Input df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'company_name': ['Apple', 'apple','apple', 'BlackBerry', 
    'blackberry','Blackberry']
})
```

Expected df

```
        company_name
0   Apple
1   apple
2   BlackBerry
3   blackberry
4   Blackberry
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `drop_duplicates` with `ignore_index=True`:

```py
df.drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
```

This outputs:

```py
  company_name
0        Apple
1        apple
2   BlackBerry
3   blackberry
4   Blackberry
```